How do you load a .1x1 (bathymetry) file in QGIS?
I have received bathymetry data in a .1x1 format, which appears to be a challenge to load directly into QGIS. The raw file is structured as a CSV with four columns, containing coordinates, depth, and date information. Here is a snippet from the file:
87997.50 436416.50 -7.92 26-03-2021
87998.50 436416.50 -7.89 26-03-2021
87999.50 436416.50 -7.88 26-03-2021
87997.50 436417.50 -7.90 26-03-2021
87998.50 436417.50 -7.88 26-03-2021
...

I want to know if there is a direct method to add this data as a raster layer in QGIS, without using any code.
When I try to add the data as a raster layer, I get the following error message:

Unsupported Data Source: C:[...]\A20210209.1x1 is not a supported
raster data source Ungridded dataset: At line 66, change of Y
direction


I saved your data snipped as "bathy.1x1" and used Layer - Add Raster Layer. No problem.

If the whole dataset does not open you may need to sort the rows https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/xyz.html

The following data organization are supported :
Cells with same Y coordinates must be placed on consecutive lines. For
a same Y coordinate value, the lines in the dataset must be organized
by increasing X values. The value of the Y coordinate can increase or
decrease however.
or, starting with GDAL 3.2.1, cells with same X coordinates must be
placed on consecutive lines. For a same X coordinate value, the
columns must be organized by increasing or decreasing Y values. For
that organization, no missing value is supported, and the whole
dataset will be ingested into memory (thus the driver will limit to
100 million points).


Thanks for the suggestion! What do you suggest is the best way of sorting this data (in QGIS)?

I have used Excel or imported data into a database (PostgreSQL, SQLite) for sorting.
